# Xcode 3/4 Compatibility when referencing static libraries

Tags: xcode, linker, static-libraries

We have multiple development machines, some running Xcode 3.2.5 and others running Xcode 4.2. We have a static library that is referenced by our project. It contains Objective C categories, so we need to use the -force_load flag with the path to the library.

The problem that we are having is that on Xcode 4.2, the library is linked from a different location than the path that we specified in -force_load. This causes duplicate symbol errors since it's trying to link two copies of the same library.

The path Xcode 4.2 links from is: 
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME-ehxeazvigqrpvogkxlkcmdzpisdw/Build/Products/CONFIGURATION-PLATFORM/

whereas the location that Xcode 3.2.5 links from is:
PROJECT_ROOT_OF_STATIC_LIBRARY/build/CONFIGURATION-PLATFORM/

Is there a way to get Xcode 4.2 to use the same locations as Xcode 3.2.5 when linking static libraries so that we can use the force_load linker option? If not, can anyone suggest an alternative solution to get Xcode 3.2.5 and 4.2 to play nicely together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are doing things the hard way.

I've never used -force_load to load static libraries. With the libraries I use, they are all stored as frameworks in a directory on my system which is separate from the project. I then use the XCode standard add frameworks dialogs to bring them into the project and "-ObjC -all_load" to ensure they work and categories are active.

I've successfully move a few projects from XCode 3 to 4 and not had the problem you are mentioning. I suspect that if you can stop using -force_load your problems will go away.

Comment: We tried using all_load, but another static library ended up giving duplicate symbol errors so we switched to force load to ensure only the library with categories would be forced.

Comment: After looking at the other static library again, I realized what was causing the duplicate symbol errors and fixed it. So now -all_load works. Thanks!